# Run async tasks and one utility function in parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I have a question about concurrency in c#. I have 3 tasks A, B,C and I am using

await `task.WhenAll(A,B,C)` to run them in parallel and then using their results like this:

```
var aresult = A.Result;
var bresult = B.Result;
var cResult = C.Result;
```

Recently I need to add a utility function that uses the cResults and return a value like this: (this function is not async method)

```
var sortedResult = SortResult(cResult);
```

I have this knoweldege that the task A and B takes much longer than task C and would like to optimize the process and have tasks (A and B) and (C and the sortedResults(cResults)) runs in parallel so that I use the same time that takes longer for A and B to process C and sortedResults(cResult). How can I do that?

Sorry for long post and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

`await task.WhenAll(A,B,C)` *doesn't* execute tasks in parallel.  What it does it it takes 3 *already executing tasks* and ensures that the method continues executing when they're all done.  You have *already* started executing the tasks in parallel just by creating `A`, `B`, and `C` (presumably by calling some asynchronous method).

So if the semantics that you want is to start A B, and C, then do something when C is finished, then do something else when A and B have finished, then just write out each of those operations.  Starting A, B, and C is as easy as calling the 3 async methods, doing something after `C` finishes is as easy as awaiting C, and doing something after A and B finish is as easy as awaiting A and B (or using `Task.WhenAll` and providing those two tasks, it would have the same effect).

Comment: what I want is that tasks A,B runs in parallel with task C and the sortResult(cResult)

Comment: @pojroj And the sequence that I described would accomplish that.